# @Transactional annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have written the below code to implment the transaction management of spring using @transactional annotation. I still feel some changes are required 
in my DAO layer. May I know what changes are required . Thanks in advance

```
    @Controller
    public class RestController {


    @Autowired
    DataServices dataServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1/dist_list/{emailId}/members", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String getDistributionListMember(@PathVariable String emailId) throws Exception, SpringException {



            String retStatus = null;


            retStatus = dataServices.getDistributionListMember(emailId, callerId);

         ]
    }      

    }
```

DataServices.java

```
    package com.uniteid.services;

    import com.uniteid.model.AIWSuser;

    public interface DataServices {


        public String getDistributionListMember(final String emailId, final String callerID) throws Exception;



    }
```

Below is my service layer where I added the trasactional attribute

```
    package com.uniteid.services;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import com.uniteid.dao.DataDao;
    import com.uniteid.model.AIWSuser;

    @Service("dataService")
    public class DataServicesImpl implements DataServices {

        @Autowired
        DataDao dataDao;


        @Transactional
        public String getDistributionListMember(String emailId, String callerID)
                throws Exception {
            return dataDao.getDistributionListMember(emailId, callerID);
        }



    }
```

Below is my spring-config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.uniteid.controller" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven
            content-negotiation-manager="contentNegociationManager" />

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="classpath:uniteidrest.properties" />
            <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />

            <property name="url">
                <value>${eidms.url}</value>
            </property>
            <property name="username">
                <value>${eidms.username}</value>
            </property>
            <property name="password">
                <value>${eidms.password}</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
            /> <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@nyvm0467.ptc.un.org:1521:EIDMSUAT" 
            /> <property name="username" value="DBO_EIDMSUAT" /> <property name="password" 
            value="NewPassDBO_EIDMSUAT" /> </bean> -->

        <bean id="contentNegociationManager"
            class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
            <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.uniteid.model.User</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="txManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
            class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

        <bean id="dataDao" class="com.uniteid.dao.DataDaoImpl"></bean>
        <bean id="dataServices" class="com.uniteid.services.DataServicesImpl"></bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </beans>
```

It still feel I have not implemented the Transactional management properly in the below code. May I know what part of the code can be removed for me to implement it

```
    package com.uniteid.dao;


    import java.sql.CallableStatement;

    import java.sql.Connection;

    import java.sql.SQLException;

    import java.sql.Types;

    import java.text.ParseException;

    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

    import org.hibernate.Session;

    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

    import org.hibernate.Transaction;

    import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


    import com.uniteid.controller.RestController;

    import com.uniteid.model.AIWSuser;

    import com.uniteid.model.User;


    public class DataDaoImpl implements DataDao 
    {



    @Autowired
        \
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    Session session = null;

    Transaction tx = null;


    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataDaoImpl.class);





    public String getDistributionListMember(final String emailId, final String callerID) throws Exception {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            final String[] returnVal2 = { "" };

            session.doWork(new Work() {
                public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                    CallableStatement stmt = null;
                    String returnVal = "";

                    stmt = connection.prepareCall("{?=call WS_Distributionlistmember(?,?)}");
                    stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
                    stmt.setString(2, emailId);
                    stmt.setString(3, callerID);
                    stmt.execute();
                    returnVal = stmt.getString(1);
                    logger.info("RETURN VALUE in getDistributionListMember method :::::: " + returnVal);
                    returnVal2[0] = returnVal;

                    logger.info("Return Value " + returnVal);
                    stmt.close();
                }
            });

            tx.commit();
            session.close();
            return returnVal2[0];
        }


    }
```

Comment: You have 2 TransactionManager : txManager and transactionManager. Only 1 is needed.

Comment: Instead of `openSession` use `getCurrentSession` remove transaction start and commit and closing of the session. Springs tx management does all that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
public String getDistributionListMember(final String emailId, final String callerID) throws Exception {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();//This is bad
        tx = session.beginTransaction();//This is bad
        tx.commit();//This is bad
        session.close();//This is bad
```

Correct should be:

```
public String getDistributionListMember(final String emailId, final String callerID) throws Exception {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();//good way
```

It is because you told spring to autowired `sessionFactory` and from now on spring is managing your hibernate session not you. So `getCurrentSession()` is correct way.

@M. Deinum Thanks to point it out.

Comment: He already has a transaction so he shouldn't be messing around wth transactions himself. To the correct way would be to get the session and ignore the transaction (that is the whole point of `@Transactional`).

Comment: Now i see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bean declaration for bean id `transactionManager` and set `txManager` instead of `transactionManager` in transaction-manager value. As you are using hibernate with spring so `HibernateTransactionManager` should be used instead of  `DatabaseTransactionManager` to define transaction boundary. `DatabaseTransactionManager` is used when you directly interact with data source without using any ORM or JPA framework.

In your service class define transaction boundary for method as below annotation

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
```